# $3628200$ in $3$ characters

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

My friend gave me and some other friends this mathematical puzzle, that I can't even come close to solving:

> Can you simplify 3,628,200 in 3 characters?

By "3 characters", he means that you can type the representation of the number in 3 or less characters (bytes don't matter). For example, $3+2$ is 3 characters.

$10!$ is the closest I've gotten, only $600$ away. There are no restrictions, any (previously known) special functions, tricks or underhandedness is completely fine.

Comment: If you aren't restricted to base 10, this is trivial! But then I suppose that's cheating.

Comment: @Samadin How exactly is it trivial? Because you still have to include the subscript or some way of identifying what base the number is in. The answer should be self-contained.

Comment: Well, if we didn't need the subscript then it would be. We omit it for base 10 just because it's so universally used

Comment: @Samadin Yeah, so sadly the base idea won't work. One step closer, though. Good thinking.

Comment: Is it possible that your friend meant to write $3628800$?

Comment: I've tried all combinations of 3 characters and operations, being sure not to count exponents/multiplication as characters, and being creative with the order of operations (through a script). It's not in the OEIS. I'm stumped.

Comment: We got no addition or subtraction,no brackets,no integration,no multiplication,no division,also $6047$ is a prime which divides $3628200$ so no factorials,tetration,logarithms,exponentation,no functions because no brackets,also it doesn't seem to be a Fibonacci number or a Bell number or a Stirling's number. Maybe some binary operation could work though slim chances there as both arguments have to be $1$ digit.

Comment: @MichaelLugo Nope. He specifically said it wasn't.

Comment: Question better suits for SE Puzzling. Special function hint might be here as a wrong answer: http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/numerical-value-15c5--3-628-200-b-360-360-c-18-018-d-3-003-q1095611  Another option put it into hex #37 5C A8 and name the RGB color "blu"